# A matrix with the rank of 1 has only rational numbers. Are all the eigenvalues necessarily rational?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that all of the eigenvalues except for one are $0$. Can the last eigenvalue be non-rational?

Comment: Hint: The characteristic polynomial will have rational coefficients and will be of the form $\lambda^n+a\lambda^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has rank $1$, then all but one eigenvalues are $0$, so the value of the nonzero eigenvalue equals the trace, which is rational.

Comment: I know that the second coefficient in the characteristic polynomial is the trace, but how do you know that the non-zero eigenvalue itself is the trace?

Comment: And by the way, I intuitively understand that if the rank is one there's only one non-zero eigenvalue but can't seem to find a proof.

Comment: Try proving that the sum of eigenvalues equals the trace. As for the other question, suppose you have two distinct eigenvectors, and find a contradiction with $rank=1$

Comment: Well I thought about the jordan form and the diagonal form but not every matrix is diagonalizeable or similar to a jordan form matrix under the rationals. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The fact that $\sum \lambda_i=\text{tr}$ is always true (this has nothing to do with rationals) and yes, it can be proven via Jordan forms for example.

Comment: @PartnersFan92, it is not true that "if the rank is one there's only one non-zero eigenvalue". Truth is: Number of non zero evalues can be atmost one. e.g $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ doesn't have any non zero eigenvalue.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 I advise you not to use Jordan form for a simple issue like this one...

Answer (score 1):

In char polynomial, coefficient of $\lambda^{n-i}$ is sum of all principal minors of order $i$. Since rank is one all minors of order $2$ or greater are zero. So only coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ has possibility to be non zero. If it too is zero. all evalues will be zero, so rational. If it is non zero, again it has two be rational since char polynomial of a rational matrix has only rational entries.

Hence eigenvalues are necessarily rational.